# How to get variable value in Native java to Flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, native

My app receives data from Bluetooth and I have stored it in a variable in Java(Native).I can display in toast message.Need to move the value to flutter
I have to display the value in the flutter in initstate. Can anyone help me?
My handler.

```
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
                     readMessage = null;
                    try {
                        readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, "UTF-8");
                                               

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MEssage"+readMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                if(msg.what == CONNECTION_STATUS){
                    if(msg.arg1 == 1)
                    {
                        bluetoothStatus=true;
                        result.success(bluetoothStatus);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        bluetoothStatus=false;
                        result.success(bluetoothStatus);

                    }

                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a recipe to do just that in the official documentation (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)
Basically you need to write a method in Java and invoke it by name in Flutter; since it will by asynchronous you might use a FutureBuilder like this

```
 class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final Future<String> _calculation = Future<String>.delayed(
    const Duration(seconds: 2),
    () => 'Data Loaded',
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _calculation, 
     .........
```

Comment: yeah.......but I'm getting data from bluetooth and storing in a String variable  using my hander...I can read message and can display in toast ........I have problem in displaying in flutter UI.....